# свекОлка, но не свёколка

Tags: орфоэпия

Свёкла - у нас признаётся нормативным вариантом, свекл**а** - просторечным. Никто не спорит.
Но при этом во всех словарях свек**о**лка, св**ё**колка даже не упоминается.

Как такое получилось? Бр**ю**ква-бр**ю**ковка, хотя тут особенности этого "ква"<"кы", возможно. Но других образцов я вообще не вижу.

*На всякий случай: в правильности словарных вариантов нимало не сомневаюсь. Вопрос именно в том, как получилось, что ударение съехало там, где по логике должно быть стабильно.*

Comment: В прошлое воскресение был в гостях у своих родственников и заметил, что они говорят как раз "свёколка". Подумал, что так правильно, молодцы, проверять не стал. Я к тому, что всё-таки так говорят.

Answer (score 1):

> Свёкла - у нас признаётся нормативным вариантом, свекла -
>   просторечным.

Это сегодня. А что было в древнерусском?

Вот как объясняет происхождение слова ***свёкла*** Шанский:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прослушал [здесь](https://translate.google.com/#el/ru/seukla), как звучит слово *seukla* в греческом.

Услышал: с[е]фкла.

В древнерусском после "***eu > ве*** в результате метатезы и изменения ***u*** в ***в***" (см. выше) сегодняшняя ***свёкла***, полагаю, первоначально тоже могла произноситься (как и в греческом) со звуком [е] и, что не исключено, ударением на последнем слоге: *свекл**а***. От этой формы и могли пойти  слова *свек**о**льный, свек**о**лка…*

Из Зализняка:

> У небольшого числа слов имеется та индивидуальная особенность, что все
>   закреплённые узусом производные от них как бы образованы от основы с
>   иной, чем в исходном слове, акцентуацией… Все они ведут себя при
>   словообразовании так, как если бы имели неподвижное ударение на
>   последнем слоге основы… Слова ***сОкол, свЁкла*** (схема ***а***)
>   проявляют себя как * ***сокОл***, * ***свеклА*** (схема ***b***)… Как
>   показывает история, **в большинстве указанных здесь случаев аномалия
>   возникла за счёт изменения акцентуации исходного слова (тогда как в
>   производных изменения не было)**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никто не спорит, что до века XV на месте современного ё **везде** было е. Только это никак не ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Почему же не ответ? Ваш вопрос звучал так: "Как получилось, что ударение съехало..."? В моём ответе предполагается, что оно в производных от _свёклы_ словах никуда и не съезжало, а осталось таким же, каким было и сотни лет назад. Произошло другое: изменилось произношение производящего слова.

Comment: *осталось таким же, каким было и сотни лет назад* - во-первых, совершенно непонятно, откуда вы это взяли. Во-вторых, разве я устанавливал какие-то временные рамки? Хорошо, почему оно съехало "в производных" ранее этих сотен лет, при заимствовании, хотя бы? Это-то совсем странно. Заимствованные слова сохраняют ударение. Вы же не будете утверждать что все эти прилагательные-уменьшительные напрямую из греческого пришли?!)))

Comment: Фактически у вам только цитата из Зализняка имеет какое-то от ношение к вопросу, но и она только констатирует факт, но не дает объяснения. Может, цитату без контекста привели, ссылочкой не порадуете на полный текст?

Comment: Свёкла, **полагаю**, первоначально тоже могла произноситься (как и в греческом) со звуком [е] и, что не исключено, ударением на последнем слоге: свекл**а** (я подкорректировал свой ответ). Про ударение -- моё предположение. Может, я и не прав. При прослушивании греческого произношения определить ударение не сумел.

Comment: _ссылочкой не порадуете на полный текст?_ === https://books.google.ru/books?id=GSPOAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%22+%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjygKrMj9TJAhWEfnIKHfwnDO04HhDoAQgfMAE#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%22%20%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&f=false

Comment: А, теперь понял... Прошу прощения. Но теперь мне надо подумать. Что-то мне подсказывает, что свёклу сюда могли и ошибочно записать...

Comment: И вот здесь еще послушайте ))) https://translate.google.com/#ru/el/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0 и здесь https://translate.google.com/#el/en/%CF%83%CE%B5%CF%8D%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%B1

Comment: Прослушал. Да, ударение на первом слоге. Ну, значит моё предположение было неверным. Хотя... Может, оно в греческом тыщу лет назад было на другом месте? Буду думать, а пока иду спать. Спокойной ночи!